# How can I add multiple indexes to a property?

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have an entity named `DomainEventLogs` which has a nullable `PublishedUtc` DateTime.

My persistence is SQL Server, and I want to have two indexes on that property. Once for yselecting rows where `PublishedUtc` is `null`, and another for selecting the most recent `PublishedUtc` rows.

This is the entity type configuration I specified

```cs
internal class DomainEventLogPersistenceConfigurationForSqlServer : IEntityTypeConfiguration<DomainEventLog>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<DomainEventLog> builder)
    {
        // This is fast for finding rows with PublishedUtc = null
        builder
            .HasIndex(x => x.PublishedUtc)
            .HasDatabaseName("IX_DomainEventLogs_PublishedUtcIsNull")
            .HasFilter($"{nameof(DomainEventLog.PublishedUtc)} is null");

        // This is fast for finding most recently published rows.
        // This is useful for event replay after a disaster recovery.
        builder
            .HasIndex(x => x.PublishedUtc)
            .IsDescending()
            .HasDatabaseName("IX_DomainEventLogs_PublishedUtcNotNullDescending")
            .HasFilter($"{nameof(DomainEventLog.PublishedUtc)} is not null");
    }
}
```

But EFCore only seems to allow one index per property. It always only adds the last one. If I add the second in a following migration then it drops the first.

**Explanation**

My table will have lots of rows added with `PublishedUtc` set to null, and then this column will be updated only once at a later point in time.

At some point, I might need to select the rows from the X number of days in order to re-publish them.

I don't want a single descending index because `null` will be inserted at the start of the index every time I insert a new row, which is not optimal. I don't want a single ascending index because it will not be used when I do an `ORDER BY [PublishedUtc] DESC` to replay events.

(This is the [Transactional outbox pattern](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/transactional-outbox.html), for those who are familiar with it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation states that only one index per property (or more precisely distinct set of properties) is supported.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/indexes

> Note
>
> By convention, an index is created in each property (or set of properties) that are used as a foreign key.
>
> EF Core only supports one index per distinct set of properties. If you configure an index on a set of properties that already has an index defined, either by convention or previous configuration, then you will be changing the definition of that index. This is useful if you want to further configure an index that was created by convention.

**However**, you can use the overload second parameter on HasIndex to achieve what you need.

For example:

```cs
internal class DomainEventLogPersistenceConfigurationForSqlServer : IEntityTypeConfiguration<DomainEventLog>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<DomainEventLog> builder)
    {
        // This is fast for finding rows with PublishedUtc = null
        builder
            .HasIndex(x => x.PublishedUtc, "IX_DomainEventLogs_PublishedUtcIsNull")
            .HasFilter($"{nameof(DomainEventLog.PublishedUtc)} is null");

        // This is fast for finding most recently published rows.
        // This is useful for event replay after a disaster recovery.
        builder
            .HasIndex(x => x.PublishedUtc, "IX_DomainEventLogs_PublishedUtcNotNullDescending")
            .IsDescending()
            .HasFilter($"{nameof(DomainEventLog.PublishedUtc)} is not null");
    }
}
```

Documentation should be added soon:
https://github.com/dotnet/EntityFramework.Docs/issues/4582

Comment: Thanks! I think the name part only needs to be "PublishedUtcIsNull" and not the whole index name.

Comment: No worries @PeterMorris I came here asking the same question and likely found the discussion on the documentation.

Comment: @PeterMorris
You need the prefix "IX_DomainEventLogs_" if that is how you want to name your indexes. I tested it on a new migration, and it renamed the indexes to the second parameter.

Also, I can't find anything in the EF code that adds the prefix. However, it might be there, so please correct me if you think I'm wrong.
[link](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/main/src/EFCore/Metadata/Internal/Index.cs)